# How to Export Virtualbox to other PC

Tags: virtualbox

Hi I have just downloaded an Ubuntu Box and installed all web dev tools I need. Now I want to get a copy of this settings as is and use it from a place without internet connection.

What should I do to get a complete backup of my virtual box so I can use it at home? What files I need to copy.

Note: I am using Virtualbox and Vagrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual box has export and import appliance features. Use them.
[image]